# I'm getting game crashes on windows 10, someone can look at the debugger output (dump)?

Tags: drivers, crash

I have reproducable crashing on software that has compatibility across all previous versions, but now on  the Windows 10 preview it continuously crashes, as for the game's part, it's not caused by the software itself as everything points in the direction of an ATI driver component that causes the crashes, thus game-technically nothing much can be reached or debugged. If anyone here has experience with these sort of crashdumps or atleast the stack messages this dump clearly provides and can give an probable cause of the crash I would be very happy.. I'm not into D3D/graphics development myself nor can I make anything readable out of the debugger output.

It's the game Multi Theft Auto that's crashing on an ATI module, an MP engine for SA that functions across everything but for limited group of users (as for me now) not, or limited to me, no idea.

Debugger output: http://pastebin.com/Bd4NPvKB

If you have a debugger with more (ati) symbols then here's the dumpfile itself:
https://mega.co.nz/#!BEESVAqL!ynbyXuyad7vOSMuaxYzsRypa9f__6_9mHbungAUIDes

These are the crash params:

Version = 1.4-release-6949.0.000
Time = Fri Nov 28 17:44:01 2014
Module = C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\atiumdag.dll
Code = 0xC0000005
Offset = 0x00027ED5

EAX=00000000  EBX=06D7899C  ECX=00000001  EDX=00000000  ESI=06D7899C
EDI=0E322B44  EBP=0029F15C  ESP=0029EF48  EIP=6CCF7ED5  FLG=00010246
CS=0023   DS=002B  SS=002B  ES=002B   FS=0053  GS=002B

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions about bugs in Pre-release software are off topic for us.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to be seen here. The faulting instruction was

```
6ccf7ed5 f7421800040000  test    dword ptr [edx+18h],400h
```

But edx had a zero in it, so this referred to address 0x18, which of course is a never-defined address (as are all va's from 0 through 0xFFFF).

As to how edx got a zero in it, we can't tell. It may have been loaded from memory by the previous instruction:

```
6ccf7ecf 8b9624040000    mov     edx,dword ptr [esi+424h]
```

esi contains a reasonable-looking address; this instruction would have loaded edx from the dword at 0x06d78dc0.  But we can't see that memory location in a minidump, and anyway there is no proof that the instruction flow came through the previous instruction; the test instruction might have been JMPd or B'd to from someplace else.

Is the system completely stable under a released version of Windows? If not, suspect hardware (video card or power supply).

Other than that there is probably nothing you can do to fix it except to get an updated driver from ATI. (Or try an older one - sometimes that helps.)

And, keep in mind: These aren't even beta versions of Windows 10; they're not expected to be stable.